# How to negate regex expressions containing ranges?

Tags: java, regex-negation

I've got the following regex expression that identifies indexed variable names within a string (a symbolic math equation):

`[a-z][0-9]`

I'd like to remove all **parts** of the string that are **not** indexed variable names. I've seen negative lookahead expressions that do this, however the examples I've seen use anchors. These examples would reject the entire string if they contain a variable name, instead of replacing the parts of the string that are not variable names. Is there an efficient way of accomplishing this? I'm using Java's replaceAll() method to try and implement this:

```
String s = "5x0 +3x2 = 7"; // I should get "x0 x2" after the regex 
s.replaceAll("[a-z][0-9]", ""); // this should be negated
```

Comment: If you want your matched groups to be space-separated, you're best off using the Matcher class and assembling a new string from your capture groups.

Comment: please describe your problem output clearly. what is your output will be `x0 + x2 = 7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you want can't be done, but what *can* be done and what is easier to understand and code is:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-z][0-9]").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String variable = m.group(); // do with it what you will
}
```

Comment: This is much better approach to extracting those variable names. Thank you!